# Designing Context Free Grammar's [HW]

Tags: context-free-grammar

I've been working on this for about 5 hours for homework and I was hoping some of you guys might be able to help since CFG's are a huge part of CS.

My real trouble is with part C.

Design a CFG for each of the following languages:

A. {(a^i)(b^j)(c^k)} WHERE (i != j) AND i,j,k >= 0)

I came up with:

```
Start-> aAB | AbB
A-> epsilon | aA
B-> epsilon | C | bB
C-> epsilon | cC
```

This seems to work for bccc, abbcc, aabbb,cc so I think I am good here.

B. {(a^i)(b^j)(c^k)} WHERE (i != k) AND i,j,k >= 0)

```
Start-> aABC | ABcC
A-> epsilon | aA
B-> epsilon | bB
C-> epsilon | cC
```

This works for bc, bbcc, ab, abb, aac so all looks well for when i!=k

C. {(a^i)(b^j)(c^k)} WHERE (i != j OR i != k) AND i,j,k >= 0)

```
Start-> aABC | AbB | ABcC
A-> epsilon | aA
B-> epsilon | bB | C
C-> epsilon | cC
```

I do not think part C is correct but I believe A and B are correct. Can anyone tell me if I am right/wrong or help in anyway? I believe since in the last case I am just doing a OR, and because my A,B,C variables are pretty much the same I can get away with combining. It seems to work as bc works, acc works and many others but I get the feeling I should not simply be combining start states.

Anyone know if I am right or close or have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you are testing grammars, be sure to also test with strings that should be rejected (see @Paulo's answer for some that fail for you currently).  To solve the first two, write a grammar that represents `A^i B^j` where `i != j`; add a grammar for an arbitrary number of `c`'s onto the end of that for part 1, and add that grammar into the middle for part 2.  For part 3, remember that the union of two grammars can be easily written as a grammar.

Comment: I'm still working on things and I think the problem might be not understanding how to properly set i=j or i!=j. The book I have is cryptic and no real examples. I believe the deciding factors for i=j or i!=j depends on the start state. So to strip things down I have (Start->aAB | AbX; A-> epsilon | aA; B-> epsilon | bbB; X-> epsilon | cC. I've been playing with things and I think that is best solution. This does make sense right? I am basically branching on whether or not a and b are even or odd, so ab would be rejected now and abb would be accepted. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user591162: Instead of thinking about your grammar as a parser, think about it as a machine that generates strings.  As the first thing to try, write a grammar that generates `A^i B^j` where `i == j`; that is likely to be in your textbook.  Then think about how it works and how to adapt it for `i != j`.  By the way, thinking about even vs. odd will take you in the wrong direction for writing this grammar.

Comment: I see how to make i=j. (Start->A|AB; A->epsilon|a|Ab|AA; B->b|bB;) or at least that seems right. I just have to see if I can reverse it, but I think I will keep working on what I posted above.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: I think I might have i=j this time. (Start->A; A->epsilon|ab|aAb;) Is this right? If not I think it might be hopeless and perhaps you could break things down more?

Comment: @user591162: Yes, that is right, but you don't need the second (`A -> ab`) case as it is redundant.  Now, use that `A` (without changing it) to change `Start` to require an un-equal count; how would you define un-equal count in terms of equal count?

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: I think I have i!=j. (Start->A; A->epsilon|aA|bB; B->bB|b;), so a is accepted, ab is rejected, abb is accepted. I think I have it. In part C, how can I merge i!=j and i!=k? can I just copy my conditions for variable A,B,C over (Along with my starting conditions for S, this makes sense to me in theory).

Comment: @user591162: That isn't right; check `aabb`.  Try using the definition of `A` from the `i == j` case as is; just change how `Start` calls that rule.

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: I see what you are saying (Start->AB; A->epsilon|aAb; B->bB|b;). Which will accept aab, abb, etc. The issue I am having is that i,j can be equal to 0. So I should be able to accept just a, or b, but by doing so break other things. How can I handle if i,j=0? The solution I just posted works using i,j as >= 1. This is the reason I keep trying to add a,b or aA,bB somewhere in my solution.

Comment: The `A -> epsilon | aAb` you posted earlier works with zero elements.  Here is an explanation of how to write the `i != j` case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781775/list-of-qa-writing-grammar-for-context-free-languages

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: Ahh. I forgot I had epsilon. I've been working on this for the last 8 hours or so and I guess I need to call it quits. I'm going to go with what I posted above and use that to derive the rest of my answers. Thank you for all the help. I've also taken a look at the link you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Your first grammar matches `abc` (by Start -> AbB -> abB -> abC -> abc), so it is not a right grammar.

So, you need to make sure the `a`s and `b`s are created in the same quantity (and then some more for one of them).

The same `abc` is also matched by your second rule, where it shouldn't be permitted, too.

Comment: Would this be correct for A? (Start-> aAB | AbD ; A-> epsilon | aA ; B-> epsilon | b | C | bbB ; D-> epsilon | bB | C ; C-> epsilon | cC). I believe this makes more sense. I've been working on this for 40m and this is my best solution, basically branching on each condition to ensure there are no i equaling j's.

Comment: @user591162: Do you know how to write a grammar for `A^i B^j` where `i == j`?